# Exception thrown by @Autowired and @Required

Tags: spring

I read that the @Required annotation throw this exception if the container can't find the bean for the dependency injection:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException`

And for @Autowired the exception is: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`

Considering those scenarios:
I use @Required in a bean A to inject another bean B that does not exist, then I start the application.
I use @Autowired in a bean A to inject another bean B that does not exist, then I start the application.

i would like to know when the exception for @Required and @Autowired are thrown? is it the same time? When the spring application context is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Required` annotation is being processed by Spring using `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `@Autowired` by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. According to the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L89) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L118), respectively, these two post processors are ordered. The one for `@Autowired` has order of `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` while the one for `@Required` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1`. According to [Spring's `Ordered` interface](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/Ordered.java#L51), the lower the value higher the priority.

Based on that, I believe `@Autowired` bean post processor will run before the one for `@Required`. So, to answer your question, a possible exception for `@Autowired` will be thrown before the one for `@Required`, when the spring application context is created.